# Virtual Machine Acceleration for Android Emulator

Tags: android, virtual-machine, emulation, amd-processor

I'm attempting to configure the new Android Virtual Machine Acceleration.

I'm following the steps outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm). I get to the point where I need to execute:

```
<sdk>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe.
```

When I try and run the installer for this, it fails and says "*VT not present: Your Computer does not meet the minimum requirements for this software*".

I assume this is because I have an AMD cpu, and the required virtualization extensions isnt available.

So my question is, is there other software for AMD that i can use to get this to work?
The android dev site doesnt seem to have any information on AMD, other than mentioning  "AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)" is supported. 
I don't see why they would only support Linux?

I'm keen on getting the android emulator feeling quicker.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know it's a year later, but I had a similar problem. I'm posting this here because late last year AMD posted a free downloadable Android app player.

This (sort-of) solves the problem for people using AMD cpu's for android development.

I've been using it for development instead of the ADT Emulator (along with my own Android phone -- it give me another target to check).

[AMD Appzone](http://www.amd.com/us/vision/shop/cool-apps/Pages/cool-apps.aspx) Downloading any game or app will also install the app player. go to the 'My Apps' button at the top and you will see your app.

The app player shows up in the ADT as "samsung-gt_i9100-localhost:5555" see screenshot. This shows my phone (first one in the list) and the AppPlayer:

[image]

Comment: You can get the installer from [here](http://cdn.bluestacks.com/public/bstkappsonpc/amdapps/Downloads/bluestacks_appplayer_AMD_Installer.exe), courtesy of [this article](http://www.slashgear.com/amd-appzone-player-puts-android-apps-on-apu-pcs-27249478/). I've been looking for an alternative to AMD AppZone Player for KitKat but haven't been able to find one.

Comment: +1 This was very helpful, thanks.  Installed the player, and sure enough, it showed up as the Samsung device described above!

Answer (score 7):

The thing is, AMD basically has those exact features in their processors - only it's called something different. I guess what we really need is an equivalent driver made for AMD processors. The Intel driver is obviously looking for exactly the string "VT-x" and not seeing it since it's called something different on AMD's processors. Doubtless not an accident.

Answer (score 4):

According to the page for Windows (and I imagine this is the same for Linux, since we're talking hardware requirements here):

"Hardware requirements: Intel® processor with support for VT-x, EM64T, and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality"

If you don't have a processor with these three things, no dice.  You can check your AMD processor's specs at http://products.amd.com/ .

And,

"Intel HAXM can be used only with Android* x86 emulator images provided by Intel. 
Intel HAXM cannot be used with ARM* Android* emulator images or non-Intel x86 Android* emulator images."  In other words, you can't use an ARM image.  You have to use an Intel-supplied Android image.

Source: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows/

Comment: can share

 1>Android Intel atom image will work on Ubuntu on KVM enabled AMD proc ?

2>Android Intel atom image will work on Ubuntu on KVM enabled Intel proc, it's not windows specific (HAXM) ?  which is better?