# Android Emulator not working on AMD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I am starting the AVD from Android Studio, it shows a black blank screen for a LONG time and I do not see the home screen. I looked at a couple of Stack Overflow posts ([Virtual Machine Acceleration for Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823216/virtual-machine-acceleration-for-android-emulator) and [Android emulator system images and AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817118/android-emulator-system-images-and-amd-processor)) from pre-2013 which suggested that it is because of AMD processor (which I am using) and which does not allow installation for HAXM.

I just want to know that since 2013 has there been a solution to this problem (either from AMD or Google)? Or else what is the alternative apart from Genymotion?

[image: Emulator Home Screen]

PS: In some example on the net I have seen the same blank screen but with a keyboard on the right, below the arrow controls.

[image: AVD Configuration]

PS: AVD does not even work when I select "Intel Atom x86" or deselect "Use Host GPU".

[image: HAXM Installation Error]

Answer (score 1):

From memory, I think HAXM only works with Intel chipset, not AMD. (I have AMD, too!).

`Genymotion` is a good alternative to Android stock AVD, in terms of speed and startup. However, `Genymotion` does not support some API levels. So, depends on your requirement, you may need to use both `Genymotion` and the Android stock AVD to test for different Android API levels.

Also, with stock Android AVD, have a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) to see other parameters that you can provide when running an AVD. In particular, the **-debug-all** parameter can show debug logs that can help troubleshoot problems with an AVD. Unless you're testing sound for an app, there's no point loading audio support for an AVD. You can disable audio support by supplying the **-noaudio** parameter.

Comment: I am open to Genymotion but its free version (https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc) does not support all the features and the Android stock AVD is not even getting started, so you can see that I am stuck. You have AMD too, so do you use the free or the paid version of Genymotion? How much time does your AVD take to show the home screen?

Comment: I use the free version of `Genymotion`, the rest of my testing are done via stock Android AVD. I don't know if having 8GB of RAM makes any difference to the way AVDs are loaded and processed, or the type of graphic card used. Stock AVD startup time takes around 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 8GB RAM too. If I could ask, what are your AVD settings for RAM, CPU etc?

Comment: All options are the same as the AVD screenshot you've posted. The exceptions are: 1) My **Device** setting is "4.7" WXGA (1280x720:xhdpi)" and 2) My **SD Card Size** is set to "50". My graphic card is **GeForce 8800 GTS** (average in 2014's standard). The only other difference is that when I run an AVD in the **Android Device Chooser** screen, I click **Start | Scale display to real size** and set the **Scale** between 0.60 and 0.70. This way, it only renders a scaled-down size of an AVD, as opposed to a full display.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that 512 MB is not enough to properly emulate an xhdpi device. Try increasing the emulated RAM to at least 1024 MB and see if you can boot properly.

Comment: 512MB is more than enough RAM to run an AVD with XHDPI emulation, particular if you choose the **Use Host GPU** option. Most graphic cards produced from 2013 onwards have powerful onboard RAM of its own to assist the card with graphic computation. So, the 512MB is pretty much reserved for operations within an AVD. If you set RAM to 1024MB, you'll hang the AVD [at the logo animation screen] on some OS + AVD combination.

Comment: sorry I meant xxhdpi, as in the AVD configuration screenshot above.

Comment: Also, I'm not aware of any issue where setting the RAM size to 1024 instead of a lower number would prevent the system from booting. Do you have a concrete / reproduceable example by chance ?